# Pytest Is Taking Too Long to Compile

Tags: python, pytest

I just wanted to create this question in case anyone happens to come across the interesting problem I did when using pytest. I was running my tests by simply typing `pytest` in the terminal from a folder a few directories above my tests. The tests would run just fine but the compiling took over two seconds. It was getting annoying.

Comment: You mean test discovery, not compilation...

Comment: Thanks for the correction. You're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that running `pytest` from a directory or two above my test files, obviously, made pytest search through every one of my files in those folders to find python test files. This problem could easily be solved by giving pytest a specific file or folder to look in. (Most people would obviously know how to do that, but some might not know the relation between that and slow compiling speeds.) You can do that like this:
For a specific test file:

```
pytest topdirectory/middledirectory/bottomdirectory/tests/test_x.py
```

For a specific test folder:

```
pytest topdirectory/middledirectory/bottomdirectory/tests/
```

In summary, if you have slow compiling speeds with pytest, try specifying the directory or file your test(s) are in.

Comment: Or use [`norecursedirs`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/2.8.7/customize.html#confval-norecursedirs) to skip directories that don't have any tests, like `src` or `.git`.

Comment: in my case it takes 20 seconds to load, even by specifying a test file with 2 unit tests inside.